# Run heredoc formated script on background?

Tags: linux, bash, heredoc

I would like to know if there are any ways to run the script in  heredoc  format on the background?

```
#!/bin/bash

python <<EOF
import time
time.sleep(2)
print "AAA"
EOF  # placing "&" here doesn't work

echo "Hello"
```

I know that I can write it to a file and then run it like `python foo.py &` but that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just stick your `&` at the top, which is totally not intuitive, but... neither are heredocs.

```
#!/bin/bash

python <<EOF &
import time
time.sleep(2)
print "AAA"
EOF 

echo "Hello"
```

You can also redirect up there too:

```
#!/bin/bash

python <<EOF > /some/file &
import time
time.sleep(2)
print "AAA"
EOF 

echo "Hello"
```

Comment: You just have to keep in mind that the here document doesn't actually start until the next line, not immediately after the `<<EOF`.